# How to merge files from keyword filename?

Tags: bash, shell

I have many files in a folder, contain

```
4628_group_1
3643_group_0
7578_group_1
4684_group_0
```

Finally, I merge file into 2 groups

```
Group1.csv is merged from 4628_group_1 and 7578_group_1
Group0.csv is merged from 3643_group_0 and 4684_group_0
```

Comment: What do you mean merge? You mean like `cat 4628_group_1 7578_group_1 > Group1.csv`? You are merging non `.csv` files into a `.csv` file?

Comment: Yes, I need to merge .csv to .csv file.

Comment: So did my answer work or did you mean something else by merge?

Comment: @WINC. Please show example contents of at least two 'group_0' files and desired output.  Only then can we ensure we are understand the requirements

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by merge, you may be able to achieve this with two simple cat commands.

```
cat *_group_0 > Group0.csv
cat *_group_1 > Group1.csv
```